# Как задать определенное количество символов при выводе числа? c#

Tags: c#

Как задать определенное количество символов при выводе числа? Не Math.Around(), там прям количество задаешь при помощи нулей. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очевидно вы имеете в виду это:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.000}", Math.PI);
```

Подробная документация на MSDN начинается тут, далее по ссылкам внутри:
**[Составное форматирование](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx)**

конкретно ваш случай тут:
**[Строки настраиваемых числовых форматов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)**